# unable to read data from sensor over i2c using STM32 nucleo

Tags: c

I am new to the whole stm32 environment. I'm a trying to read the distance from the Aconeer XM132 over I2C, but i'm having a really hard time setting up an i2c connection between a nucleo board and the sensor.

Here is the code I am using, and it seems pretty straigh foward to me, the problem is that I am unable to get any information from the sensor.

I don't think the wiring is the problem. I am also using a logic analyzer to monitor the communication, but both SCL and SDA are alway LOW.

Thank you in advance for the help!

````
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdarg.h"
#include "string.h"

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_FS;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t u8TxDone = 0U;
#define MASK_READY          0x01
#define XM132_ADDR          0x51<<1
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_PCD_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
static uint16_t Buffercmp(uint8_t* pBuffer1, uint8_t* pBuffer2, uint16_t BufferLength);

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    u8TxDone = 1U;
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
      HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

/* Configure the peripherals common clocks */
  PeriphCommonClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_PCD_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  /***************************************************************** GENERAL REGISTERS *******************************************************************/
    uint8_t ID_REG[2U]; //READ
    ID_REG[0] = 0xF8;
    ID_REG[1] = 0x10;
    uint8_t ID_buffer[4U];

    /*** Mode selection ***/
    uint8_t MODE_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; //LSB 0x01 = Power bin mode, 0x0200 = Distance detector mode
    uint8_t MODE_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x02};
    uint8_t buffer_MODE[4U];

    /*** Main control ***/
    uint8_t DETECT_ON_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    uint8_t DETECT_ON_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x03};
    uint8_t buffer_DETECT_ON[4U];

    uint8_t DETECT_OFF_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    uint8_t DETECT_OFF_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x03};
    uint8_t buffer_DETECT_OFF[4U];

    /*** Streaming control ***/
    uint8_t UART_STREAM_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};// 01 enables UART Streaming, 00 disable UART Streaming
    uint8_t UART_STREAM_REGR[2U];
    uint8_t buffer_UART_STREAM[4U];

    /*** Status Clear ***/
    uint8_t STATUS_CLEAR_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x03, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; //Same register as for main control
    uint8_t STATUS_CLEAR_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x03};
    uint8_t buffer_STATUS_CLEAR[4U];

    /*** Status Value ***/
    uint8_t STATUS_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x06}; //
    uint8_t buffer_STATUS[4U];
    /****************************DISTANCE REGISTERS ***********************/
    uint8_t RANGE_START_REGW[6U]; //= {0xF9, 0x20, 0xE0, 0x03}; //write 0x03E8 into 0x20
    RANGE_START_REGW[0] = 0xF9;
    RANGE_START_REGW[1] = 0x20;
    RANGE_START_REGW[2] = 0x41; //0xE8  0x41
    RANGE_START_REGW[3] = 0x00; //0x03
    RANGE_START_REGW[4] = 0x00;
    RANGE_START_REGW[5] = 0x00;
    uint8_t RANGE_START_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x20};
    uint8_t buffer_RANGE_START[4U];

    uint8_t RANGE_LENGTH_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x21, 0x96, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    /******Profile selection**********/
    uint8_t PROFILE_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x28, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00};
    uint8_t PROFILE_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x28};
    uint8_t buffer_PROFILE[4U];

    /***** Gain ******/
    uint8_t GAIN_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x24, 0xE8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00}; //Gain = 1000
    uint8_t GAIN_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x24};
    uint8_t buffer_GAIN[4U];

    uint8_t DOWNSAMPLING_FACTOR_REGW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x29, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};


    uint8_t NUMBER_PEAK_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB0};
    uint8_t buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[4U];


    uint8_t DISTANCE1_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB1}, DISTANCE2_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB3}, DISTANCE3_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB5}, DISTANCE4_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB7};
    uint8_t buffer_DISTANCE[4U];

    uint8_t AMPLITUDE1_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB2}, AMPLITUDE2_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB4}, AMPLITUDE3_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB6}, AMPLITUDE4_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0xB8};
    uint8_t buffer_AMPLITUDE[4U];

    /*** MUR: Maximum Unambiguous Range ***/
    uint8_t MUR_REW[6U] = {0xF9, 0x34, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    uint8_t MUR_REGR[2U] = {0xF8, 0x34};
    uint8_t buffer_MUR[4U];

    /***********************GET MODULE ID***************************/
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, MODE_REGW, 6, 5000); // SET DEVICE MODE
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, RANGE_START_REGW, 6, 5000); //SET START RANGE
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, RANGE_LENGTH_REGW, 6, 5000); //SET RANGE LENGTH
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, PROFILE_REGW, 6, 5000); // SET PROFILE
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DETECT_ON_REGW, 6, 5000); // CREATE AND ACTIVATE CURRENT SERVICE AND DETECTOR
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, GAIN_REGW, 6, 5000); // CONFIGURE GAIN

    uint32_t StatusReg = 0U;
    uint32_t NumberOfPeak = 0U;
    uint32_t Distance1 = 0U, Amplitude1 = 0U, OldDistance1 = 0U, OldAmplitude1 = 0U;
    uint32_t Distance2 = 0U, Amplitude2 = 0U;
    uint32_t Distance3 = 0U, Amplitude3 = 0U;
    uint32_t Distance4 = 0U, Amplitude4 = 0U;
    uint8_t counter  = 0U;

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_Delay(300);

        HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, STATUS_CLEAR_REGW, 6, 5000);

        do
        {
            HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, STATUS_REGR, 2, 5000);
            HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_STATUS, 4, 5000);

        }
        while ((buffer_STATUS[1U] & MASK_READY) == 0x00); // DATA READY

        HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, NUMBER_PEAK_REGR, 2, 5000);
        HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_NUMBER_PEAK, 4, 5000);

        NumberOfPeak = buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[1U] << 8U)
                                        + ((uint32_t)buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[3U] << 24U);

        if (NumberOfPeak > 0)
        {
            vPrint("NumberOfPeak %d \r\n", NumberOfPeak);

            if(NumberOfPeak == 1)
            {

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE1_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE1_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance1 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude1 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[3U] << 24U);
            }
            else if(NumberOfPeak == 2)
            {

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE1_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE1_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance1 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude1 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE2_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE2_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance2 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude2 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);
            }

            else if(NumberOfPeak == 3)
            {

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE1_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE1_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance1 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                        + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude1 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE2_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE2_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance2 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                        + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude2 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE3_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE3_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance3 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                                            + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude3 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);
            }

            else if(NumberOfPeak >= 4)
            {

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE1_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE1_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance1 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                                + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude1 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE2_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE2_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance2 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                                + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude2 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE3_REGR, 2, 5000);
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE3_REGR, 2, 5000);
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance3 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                        + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude3 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);


                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE4_REGR, 2, 5000);  // Read 0xB1 DISTANCE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

                HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE4_REGR, 2, 5000); // Read 0xB2 AMPLITUDE
                HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

                Distance4 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U)
                                                                    + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[2U] << 16U) + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[3U] << 24U);

                Amplitude4 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);

            }

            if(OldDistance1 != Distance1)
                vPrint("Distance1 %d mm \r\n", Distance1);

            if(OldAmplitude1 != Amplitude1)
                vPrint("Amplitude1 %d \r\n", Amplitude1);
            //vPrint("----------------------------------------- \r\n");

            OldDistance1 = Distance1;
            OldAmplitude1 = Amplitude1;

        }
}}

    void vPrint(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
        uint8_t __au8_BufferOnlyForAssert[200U] = {0U};
        uint8_t __u8_CounterByteMsg = 0U;

        u8TxDone = 0U;

        va_list argp;
        va_start(argp, fmt);

        if(0 < vsprintf((char *)__au8_BufferOnlyForAssert, fmt, argp)) // build string
        {
            __u8_CounterByteMsg = strlen((char *)__au8_BufferOnlyForAssert);
            if(__u8_CounterByteMsg <= 200U)
            {
                if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, __au8_BufferOnlyForAssert, __u8_CounterByteMsg) != HAL_OK)
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }
                while(u8TxDone == 0U);
            }
        }

        va_end(argp);
    }
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */


/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
    void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {
      RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
      RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

      /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
      */
      __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
      /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
      * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
      */
      RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = RCC_MSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 32;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV5;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV4;
      if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /** Configure the SYSCLKSource, HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers
      */
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK4|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK2
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK2Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK4Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;

      if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
    }

/**
  * @brief Peripherals Common Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the peripherals clock
  */
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_SMPS;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsClockSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsDivSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKDIV_RANGE0;

  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Smps */

  /* USER CODE END Smps */
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x00000E14;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = XM132_ADDR;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */
  HAL_I2CEx_EnableFastModePlus(I2C_FASTMODEPLUS_I2C1);
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief LPUART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 1 */
  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 209700;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  hlpuart1.FifoMode = UART_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&hlpuart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 2 */

}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_7B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USB Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USB_PCD_Init(void)
{

  hpcd_USB_FS.Instance = USB;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.dev_endpoints = 8;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.speed = PCD_SPEED_FULL;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.phy_itface = PCD_PHY_EMBEDDED;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.Sof_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.low_power_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.lpm_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.battery_charging_enable = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_PCD_Init(&hpcd_USB_FS) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USB_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2cHandle)
{
  /** Error_Handler() function is called when error occurs.
    * 1- When Slave doesn't acknowledge its address, Master restarts communication.
    * 2- When Master doesn't acknowledge the last data transferred, Slave doesn't care in this example.
    */
  if (HAL_I2C_GetError(I2cHandle) != HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{  Error_Handler();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */```
````

Comment: When you step tbrough it with your debugger, how far does it get?

Comment: in fact i managed to get a communication with the stm32 but i think something is not write i'm getting this on the serial terminal :
-----------------------------------------                                                                  
Waiting for data ready
Receive status 1
NumberOfPeak 1792376585
-----------------------------------------                                                                                       and on the logic analyzer i'm getting : "read to 0x51 nak
write to 0x51 nak
read to 0x51 nak
write to 0x51 nak"